# why does ivy download libraries everytime

Tags: ant, build, ivy, dependency-management

I am using apache ivy with ant for managing my dependencies. The only problem is that, it starts downloading the libraries everytime I do a build or run. Is there any way in which downloading can be stopped if the previously downloaded version exists in the ivy cache and that version matches the latest version on maven repository.

For example : 
I am using jhall.jar as one of the dependencies managed by ivy. Its last version was 2.0 which published in 2010 and there hasn't been any changes since. Now if I run ant compile or ant run task then ivy downloads the sources corresponding to jhall.jar. Next time I run ant compile, it again starts downloading the same sources. I want to stop this behaviour since it wastes a lot of time and I have many such libraries.

Can somebody help? Do I have to make any changes to ivy retrieve?

Comment: Could you include copies of your ivy and ivysettings filess? It sounds like you're using dynamic revisions. This would explain a check on the last version (how does ivy know it's the latest unless it checks).

Comment: @MarkO'Connor : yes I am using some thing like
<dependency org="com.sun.woodstock.dependlibs" name="jhall" rev="latest.integration" />     . But that doesn't explain why it downloads everytime even if the same version exists already in the ivy cache on my local system. Checking is fine with me, but downloading wastes a lot of my time.

Comment: You're asking for the latest **integration** version. That means it could have changed. Try using the "checkmodified" attribute on your resolver, that might help: http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/settings/resolvers.html